# ListView with expandable itemBuilder - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to do a carousel with user reviews for my app. I want it to be displayed horizontally and with a defined height. If the review is too long, the Container shows a button to expand or collapse the container according to the review height.
The problem is that I don't know how to make the container as high as the expanded review. Any idea about how to solve it? Below is the code and a picture with the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> reviews = [
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
];

class Review extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReviewState createState() => _ReviewState();
}

class _ReviewState extends State<Review> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //! This is the height I want to fix
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: ScrollController(),
                itemCount: reviews.length,
                itemBuilder: _buildList,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, int i) {
    String firstHalf;
    String secondHalf;
    int maxLength = 150;

    final String review = reviews[i];
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final dynamic onTapFn = () {
      setState(() {
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      });
    };

    // Logic to make the body review expandable
    if (review != null && review.length > maxLength) {
      firstHalf = review.substring(0, maxLength);
      secondHalf = review.substring(maxLength, review.length);
    } else {
      firstHalf = review;
      secondHalf = "";
    }

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      width: size.width - 60,
      child: secondHalf.isEmpty
          ? Text(firstHalf)
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  isExpanded ? (firstHalf + secondHalf) : (firstHalf + "..."),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Read more",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () => onTapFn(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is the initial review]

[image: I want this container to be as high as the review]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` to the parent of `buildList` top most container when the property `isExpanded` is true.

Comment: @AshokKuvaraja Yes, but I don't want to scroll withing the review, I want the container to grow with the review